# Java, How do i use add a string and an integer to an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, int

This is the array code I have so far:

```
ArrayList<Data> arrl = new ArrayList<Data>();
    arrl.add("Tim", 23);
```

Need to know how to an integer and a string to the array.

For Example:

names: and ages:
Tim        23
Max        56
Clare      43

I know how to add integers OR strings to array-lists but i can't figure how to incorporate both in the same array.

Comment: Your `ArrayList` is meant to store `Data` objects. So add `Data` objects.

Comment: also, just for list interchangability (and a more flexible design) use the `List` interface on the assignment variable. Like: `List<Data> arrl = new ArrayList<Data>();`

Comment: Assuming you have a data class, `List<Data> arrl = new ArrayList<Data>();` then `arrl.add(new Data("Tim", 23))`. Depending on your usage (ie if you will know the names and want to look up the ages) you could use a Map instead.  If this is relevant to you I can give an example.

Comment: the OP could also use `List<Object> arrl = new ArrayList<Object>(); arrl.add("Tim"); arrl.add(new Integer(23));` -- depends what the OP is after I suppose.

Comment: @SnakeDoc While that is valid, but I can't think of a single instance where it would be beneficial to throw Strings and Integers into list together.

Comment: @turbo i can't either... unless i suppose you're just trying to shlup data around... although there's cleaner ways than that. in any case, it's just one option in a large toolbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list is taking objects of type `Data`. So, create a `Data` class that contains a `String` for the name and `int` for the age. Create a `Data` object for each entry you want and add it to your `arrl` list.

```
public class Data {

    private String name;
    private int age;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Data(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Getters and Setters go here.
}
```

In this example I used a constructor to allow easy construction of a `Data` object with a name and age.

```
List<Data> arrl = new ArrayList<Data>();
arrl.add(new Data("Tim", 23));
```

Comment: please adjust your interface usage to best practice of `List<Data> arrl = new ArrayList<Data>();`

Comment: As long as you do that, use Java 7 diamond notation :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist that is the "diamond notation" lol, it's more type-safe than just using `new ArrayList();`

Comment: Diamond notation is this: `List<Data> arrl = new ArrayList<>();`. You let the compiler figure out the generic type. It's a small difference, and I'm just jumping on the anal wagon.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a class `Person` for instance, where you save the name and age of a person.

Then, you have a `ArrayList` of `Person`, and you can store and access that information.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a class that use generics, it means type-safety, so when you declare a class that use generic in its class definition you have to declare the type when making the instance.

If you want to store `String`objects declare `ArrayList` in this way:

```
ArrayList<String> saveString = new ArrayList<String>
```

You can make a class `Person` with those instance variables and resolve your problem.
For example:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private int age;

public Person(String name,int age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

}
```

And then you can use in this way:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(new Person("Luis Alberto",15));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arraylist is made for Data objects that means you have to create Data object to put it there, `this is what i mean by that   **arrl.add(new Data("Tim",44));**
Make sure that you have class Data with constructor for string and int

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> arrl = new ArrayList<>();
        arrl.add(new Person("Tim", 23));
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    Person (String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is what is proposed by Wabs and Ashot Karakhanyan. But if your need, is to have the name and age as different items of your list, you can use the following:

```
List<Object> arrl = new ArrayList<Object>();
arrl.add("name");
arrl.add(23);
```